# Load MySQL Data with PHP but result has wrong format

Tags: php, mysql

In my application i want to load all Reservationtypes into a `<select>`with PHP. Reservationtype has 2 parameters (reservationtypeid, reservierungart). I use a Database class from [this website](https://codeshack.io/super-fast-php-mysql-database-class/) for easier SQL commands.

ReservationtypeModel

```
class Reservierungstyp
{
    public function __construct($reservationtypeid, $reservierungsart){
        $this->$reservationtypeid = $reservationtypeid;
        $this->$reservierungsart = $reservierungsart;
    }
}
```

In my ReservationtypeModel i use this method the getAllReservationtypes:

```
public function getAllReservierungstypen(){
    $db = new Database();
    $results = $db->query('SELECT * FROM reservationtype')->fetchAll();
    $rows = count($results);
    $db->close();

    $typesArray = array();

    if($rows > 0){
        foreach($results as $res){
            $r = new Reservierungstyp($res['reservationtypeid'], $res['reservierungsart']);
            $typesArray[] = $r;
        }
    }else{
        return null;
    }
    return $typesArray;
}
```

The results have a Format like this:

```
Reservierungstyp Object ( [1] => 1 [Training] => Training ) )
```

But wouldn't it have to be something like this?

```
Reservierungstyp Object ( [reservationtypeid] => 1 [reservierungart] => Training ) )
```

I don't know which error could cause this error. If there is another error with my code please let me know, i just think that this false format is the trigger for the error

Comment: if something returns Object, it's not JSON

Comment: Then what is the problem? I just thougt it was a json problem, sorry for the wrong annotation.

Comment: really hard to tell as you don't give us a class definition of `Reservierungstyp`

Comment: @FlashThunder i add this right now

Comment: ok it doesn't have anything to do with JSON then, you need to give your database table schema as well

Answer (score 0):

I think your class should be:

```
class Reservierungstyp
{
    private $reservationtypeid;
    private $reservierungsart;

    public function __construct($reservationtypeid, $reservierungsart){
        $this->reservationtypeid = $reservationtypeid;
        $this->reservierungsart = $reservierungsart;
    }
}
```

Pay attention to the __construct assignement. You used $this->$reservationtypeid (dollar before the class attribute), meaning you expect a variable, which in this case it is indeed the constructor parameters.